# Alinear puntos en el mapa

Tags: leaflet, mapa

estoy teniendo un problema que creo que no será fácil de solucionar pero me gustaría comentarlo por aquí a ver si alguien puede ayudarme. He estado recopilando datos de iluminación por las calles de mi pueblo. Voy con el coche conduciendo de noche con unos sensores de luz y un GPS. Los datos son muy sencillos: una columna con latitud, otra con longitud y otra con iluminancia.

El problema viene cuando represento los datos, que debido a la imprecisión del GPS obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los puntos se suben a la acera, incluso se meten en los edificios. La duda es: ¿habría alguna manera de alinear los puntos para que siguieran la línea de la calle? o por lo menos conseguir alinear los puntos a una recta, para que no vayan haciendo zig-zag.

Comment: Tendrías que ir punto a punto y (sumar o restar) algunos numeritos a las coordenadas. Esos datos fueron capturados por el nivel de precisión del GPS utilizado. Saludos :D